# ¿Cómo validar dos reCAPTCHA en una sola pagina HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Quiero implementar dos reCAPTCHA dentro de una sola pagina html. Estuve investigando en la documentacion y pude implementar, pero tengo una función donde al enviar el formulario valida si le dieron check al reCAPTCHA, esta función la tengo en los dos formularios.

El resultado es que en el primer reCAPTCHA al hacer check me manda un numero diferente a 0, pero en el segundo me sigue mandando 0 aun que lo haya marcado. No se que puede estar pasando, alguna idea? Dejo mi código fuente.

Este es el formulario de login del encabezado. Este encabezado lo tengo en otro html y lo llamo en donde esta el otro formulario.

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="login.asp" onsubmit="return recapt(grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1))">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pass" class="col-form-label">Contrase&ntilde;a:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passaccess" name="passaccess" maxlength="4" required>
                  </div>                
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">    
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div id="example1"></div>
                     <br/>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="success-alert">
                      <strong>Alerta </strong>No puedes avanzar sin verificar <b>reCAPTCHA</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Enviar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" id="goBack">Cerrar</button>             
                </div>
                </div>  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Este es el otro formulario de registro:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="return recapt(grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId2))">
            <div class="col-12">        
                <h5>¿Con qué frecuencia consume alguna bebida alcohólica?</h5>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pregunta_1" id="pregunta_10" value="0"  >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="pregunta_10">Nunca</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pregunta_1" id="pregunta_11" value="1"  >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="pregunta_11">Una o menos veces al mes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pregunta_1" id="pregunta_12" value="2"   >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="pregunta_12">De 2 a 4 veces al mes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pregunta_1" id="pregunta_13" value="3"   >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="pregunta_13">De 2 a 3 veces a la semana</label>            
                </div>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div id="example2"></div>
                     <br/>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="success-alert">
                      <strong>Alerta </strong>No puedes avanzar sin verificar <b>reCAPTCHA</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Enviar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" id="goBack">Cerrar</button>             
                </div>
            </div>
            

        </form>
```

Este es el código que tome de la documentación con la función donde mando una alerta pasa saber si hicieron ckeck o no:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
    async defer>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
      var widgetId1;
      var widgetId2;
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        // Renders the HTML element with id 'example1' as a reCAPTCHA widget.
        // The id of the reCAPTCHA widget is assigned to 'widgetId1'.
        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('example1', {
          'sitekey' : '6LdtxQIfAAAWJJNJN5G5E-FtXAWEDJRWD4C',
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
        widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render('example2', {
          'sitekey' : '6LdtxQIfAAAWJJNJN5G5E-FtXAWEDJRWD4C',
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
      };




function recapt(a) {
   var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    alert(response.length);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer solo fue cambiar:

```
var response = grecaptcha.getResponse(0);  
var response = grecaptcha.getResponse(1);
```

Para que identifique cada captcha